# При вставки скрипта в amo Crm выходит ошибка " Uncaught ReferenceError: amo_forms_loaded is not defined"

Tags: javascript, amocrm

Я решил вставить скрипт из конструктора AMOCRM сайта на wp и у меня не выходит форма. Выходит ошибка " Uncaught ReferenceError: amo_forms_loaded is not defined". Обращался в тех поддержку, но те руки не помогают. Может кто сталкивался с этой проблемой.